# Get value of key of object in array based on other key in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks like this. I have a countries array containing objects with `name` and `code`. Given the country name I want to return the country code.

```
var countries = [
  {
     name: 'United States', 
     code: 'US'
  },

  {
     name: 'Spain', 
     code: 'ES'
  }
];
```

I know I can do something like this, but I am sure there must be a tidier way to do this:

```
var code;

getCountryFromCode(country) {
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    if (countries[i].name === country) {
      code = countries[i].code;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using es6:

```
 countries.find(x => x.name === 'United States').code
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var countries = [
  {
     name: 'United States', 
     code: 'US'
  },

  {
     name: 'Spain', 
     code: 'ES'
  }
];
var countryName = "Spain";

console.log(countries.find(c=>c.name===countryName).code);
```